# how can I click to a link, open it on a new tab, perform some action and return to my parent window for rest operations in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

> I am trying to scrape
> "https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1".
> first I am trying to find all divs having opportunity details in it. (
> I have done with it )  I am getting some basic info from this page
> like dates and opportunity titles. but I also need to get a full
> description, for that, I must click on its title which takes us to a
> new page. I must get the description detail from this new page and go
> back to the parent page in order to scrape the next opportunities.

how can I do that? below is my code which I tried but could not get the expected result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome( options=options ,executable_path="D:/chromedriver.exe")

baseLink = "https://beta.sam.gov"
lastPageNumber = 2
currentpage = 1

# getting source code of each parent page , like page = 1,2,3 until the last page.
def startscrapping(currentpage):
    driver.get(f'https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page={currentpage}')
    source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    return soup

# getting the last index for the parent page to be scrapped
def findLastPageIndex():
    soup = startscrapping(1)
    results = soup.find("ul", {"aria-label" : "pagination"}).findAll('li',"ng-star-inserted")
    if results is not None:
        lastPageNumber= int(results[-2].text.strip())

findLastPageIndex()


while  currentpage <= lastPageNumber :
    soup = startscrapping(currentpage)
    outerDivs = soup.find_all(attrs={"tabindex": "-1" , "class": "ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"})
    print(f"page number = {currentpage}")
    for index,item in enumerate(outerDivs):
        title = item.find("h3" , class_= "opportunity-title").text.strip()

        #....some other codes for finding title and dates 

        # trying to click on the link
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='search-results']/div[{index+1}]/opportunities-result/div/div/div[1]/h3/a").click()      
    
        handles = driver.window_handles
        size = len(handles)
        print(f"length of handles  = {size}")
        parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle

        for x in range(size):
            if handles[x] != parent_handle:
                # trying to swith on the new window
                driver.switch_to.window(handles[x])
                print(driver.title)
                driver.close()
                break
        
        driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)

       
        break
        
    break
```

You also may see the pictures I attached for more info
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on the link, try scraping the link and opening the link in a new tab. Here is how u do it:

```
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a',class_ = "wordbreak")
url_lst = []
for a in a_tags:
   url_lst.append("https://beta.sam.gov/"+ a['href'])
print(url_lst)
```

Output:

```
['https://beta.sam.gov//opp/26d35e6fa6e64a8099cf37e592ea54d0/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/5a07648db5034fd590ce2d3526eea366/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/7fd9b43ec7734708b23f6cacb189bf7f/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/1a9d2d5d61ac4deba9d6cc973b684176/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/b7eb9430de724dd58bf9c4c76c0d8652/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/f70317667944475981fbcbfd52a6f86e/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/b39489e47c8a41c6801499de4d908dad/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/dcaa31871a174dd3a136b276dbf0040e/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/401b8fd7f2234ffcbf4476523413ba40/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1', 'https://beta.sam.gov//opp/7c61c39c6cd24d52bbb34feea9fcf69e/view?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1']
```

U can then iterate over this list, open all the links one by one in a new tab and perform the action that u want. Hope that this helps!

Comment: Does this answer ur question? And did it help u?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to switch over to a new tab and back to parent.

```
parent=driver.current_window_handle
#Use a for loop
   driver.execute_script("window.open('{0}', '_blank');".format(url))
   driver.switch_to.window(len(driver.window_handles)-1)
   #Do whatever you want
   driver.close()
   driver.switch_to.window(parent)
```

Comment: why do I need to use for loop? what should be iterated?

Comment: I have 1000 page, each page has 10 divs and each divs has one link which I should visit it and do my job and need to come back for the next div, again open its link,... the first page requires 10 times to be switched, and the second page again 10 times....

Comment: If you grab all the href links you could just loop them like this to go to their pages and back.

Comment: Where the url is the ahref value.